# How to back up all changes in Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, version-control

I would like to back all changes in Xcode. Currently, I create project with the same name and replace it. Maybe it is possible in Xcode to do that in other, faster and easier way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "back all changes"?

Comment: I mean that the project should look as if it had just been created.

Answer (score 1):

Use Time Machine, use git, or use snapshots in Xcode - if what you are talking about is making backups.

Time Machine is obviously a good idea even if you use git or snapshots so you get a backup when your hard drive crashes or you computer is stolen.

Comment: TimeMachine coveres Xcode's snapshot features, so snapshotting has been removed from XCode 7, now they are not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is versioning - with **Git** support - XCode offers creation of a repository for you

- by creating a brand new project
- creating repo in Xcode menu -> Source Control

Here you can read a lot:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingSourceCodeControl.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7

According to atlassian.com, versioning explained:

> Version control systems are a category of software tools that help a
>   software team manage changes to source code over time. Version control
>   software keeps track of every modification to the code in a special
>   kind of database. If a mistake is made, developers can turn back the
>   clock and compare earlier versions of the code to help fix the mistake
>   while minimizing disruption to all team members.